# Restlet URI Pattern

Tags: java, rest, pattern-matching, uri, restlet

I work on 2.1-M7 version of Restlet (I have to update it but this is an another problem)

I use directly Restlet, without any webserver before it Starting a component. Adding some virtualhosts on it.

And in the host I add entrypoints with method attach(string uriPattern, Restlet entrypoint)

**My problem is :**
When I add with attach the uri "/test" with the entrypoint Test.class (with a method who print : "hello world") with a curl I can call "/testmeagain" and it's work (return "hello world") because it's a pattern?

So I use this : http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html?is-external=true

And try "/test$" but in curl "/test" and "/testmeagain" return 404 now

Maybe I miss something?

Thank you if you have any suggestion or response to help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In fact, in Restlet, there is a matching mode for routes. Here is the behavior in the framework:

- When you attach a route on a virtual, the default mode is "STARTS WITH". So with something like `attach("/test", ...)`, URLs like `/test` and `/testsomething` will match.
- When you attach a route on a router, the default mode is "EQUALS". So with something like `attach("/test", ...)`, only URL `/test` will match.

The `attach` method returns a template route on which you can change this matching:

```
TemplateRoute route = component.getDefaultHost().attach(
        "/test", new Restlet() {
    @Override
    public void handle(Request request, Response response) {
        response.setEntity("test", MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN);
    }
});

// Default matching mode
int defaultMatching = route.getMatchingMode();
// Set another matching mode
route.setMatchingMode(Template.MODE_EQUALS);
```

In fact, it's more usually to implement a Restlet application and attach it to a virtual host on the component. In this case, you will have exact matching.

Here is the way to do:

```
Component component = new Component();
(...)
MyRestletApplication application = new MyRestletApplication();
component.getDefaultHost().attachDefault(application);
```

Here is a sample content for the application:

```
public class MyRestletApplication extends Application {
    @Override
    public Restlet createInboundRoot() {
        Router router = new Router(getContext());

        TemplateRoute route = router.attach("/test", MyServerResource.class);
        // Default matching mode
        int defaultMatching = route.getMatchingMode();

        return router;
    }
}
```

And the content of the server resource:

```
public class MyServerResource extends ServerResource {
    @Get
    public String test() throws Exception {
        return "test";
    }
}
```

Hope it helps you,
Thierry

Comment: Thank you Thierry i go work on it. Try to set matching mode without application waiting. Have a nice day